# Why do images take so long to load in this app?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-places

I just started making an app using Google Places API.  So far the app lets the user select a place and then it displays an image of the place.  However, the image takes minutes to load and sometimes doesn't load at all.  Please let me know if you see the error.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;


import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
private TextView tvName;
private TextView tvAddress;
private TextView tvAttributions;
private TextView price;
private TextView phone;
private TextView rating;
TextView id;
ImageView downloadedImg;
CharSequence placeID;
String photoReference;


public void logStuff (){
     //
          ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();
     Bitmap myImage;
     try {
         myImage = task.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=500&maxheight=500&photoreference=" + photoReference + "&key=APIKEY").get();
        downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(myImage);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Log.i("button", "tapped");
    Log.i("imageurl", (String) placeID);
}





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    tvAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attributions);
    price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
    phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    rating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
    id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeId);
    downloadedImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);






}

public void onPickButtonClick(View v) {
    // Construct an intent for the place picker
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
        // Start the intent by requesting a result,
        // identified by a request code.
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        // The user has selected a place. Extract the name and address.
        final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

        final CharSequence name = place.getName();
        final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
        final int priceLevel = place.getPriceLevel();
        final CharSequence phoneNum = place.getPhoneNumber();
        final float rate = place.getRating();
        placeID = place.getId();
        logStuff();

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;


        try {

            result = task.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" + placeID + "&key=APIKEY").get();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("photo_reference\" : \"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
            while (m.find()) {
         photoReference =  m.group(1);
                Log.i("PLACE", photoReference);

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Log.i("Contents Of URL", result);



        String attributions = PlacePicker.getAttributions(data);
        if (attributions == null) {
            attributions = "";
        }
        tvName.setText(name);
        tvAddress.setText(address);



    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
}
```

ImageDownloader.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>  {


@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        return myBitmap;


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

DownloadTask.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String result = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urls[0]);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = reader.read();

        while (data != -1) {

            char current = (char) data;

            result += current;

            data = reader.read();

        }

        return result;

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return "Failed";

    }


}
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PlacePickerActivity">

<!--including the toobar-->
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/attributions"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/attributions"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/attributions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="attributions"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:onClick="onPickButtonClick"
    android:text="Find a location"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:background="#ebb70d"
    android:layout_above="@+id/attributions"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Rating:"
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Phone"
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Price"
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="place Id"
    android:id="@+id/placeId"
    android:layout_below="@+id/price"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:maxHeight="500dp"
    android:maxWidth="500dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

NOTE: If you wish to test this, you will need to input your own api key